# How to calculate interval between datetime in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

For example,how to calculate the interval between these two datetime:

2009-09-18 00:00:00

2009-10-17 00:00:00

**EDIT**

I mean to get the interval in the format of year-month-day hour:min:seconds

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about using [`datediff`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) :

```
mysql> select abs(datediff('2009-09-18 00:00:00', '2009-10-17 00:00:00'));
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| abs(datediff('2009-09-18 00:00:00', '2009-10-17 00:00:00')) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                          29 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Quoting the manual :

> `DATEDIFF()` returns `expr1 – expr2`
>   expressed as a value in days from one
>   date to the other. expr1  and expr2
>   are date or date-and-time expressions.
>   
> Only the date parts of the values are
>   used in the calculation.

Answer (score 5):

You may try out [`DATEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) or [`TIMEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Answer (score 5):

Or use timestampdiff() like this:

> timestampdiff(microsecond,yourtime,now())

the first parameter is mysql datetime unit, can be "microsecond, second, minute, hour, day, year", and this function means the 3rd parameter datetime minus the 2nd parameter datetime.

```
mysql> select timestampdiff(second, "2009-09-18 00:00:00", "2009-10-17 00:00:00");
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| timestampdiff(second, "2009-09-18 00:00:00", "2009-10-17 00:00:00") |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                             2505600 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just subtract datetimes and it will return the value:

select (now() - interval 2 day) - (now() - interval 5 day);

The result isn't a datetime (it's some decimal coded date -- 3000000 for three days in this case), but it isn't correct to say consider a datetime and an interval as the same datatype.